# Flutter iOS build failure error with Multiple commands produce 'build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework'

Tags: flutter, xcode

```
Launching lib/flavor/main_dev.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
main_dev.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            8.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/Users/subhangipawar/Documents/BrainvireProject/main_court/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework'

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited
```

Xcode version -  14.3

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Getting this error in ios simulator PFA SS of xcode build phases
[image]